# Is it still possible to get the Replayer achievement in Street Fighter IV, or is the Replay Channel broken?

Tags: achievements, super-street-fighter-iv, ultra-street-fighter-iv

I recently started playing *Super Street Fighter IV: Arcade Edition Ultra* (released for Xbox 360 in 2011 with the Ultra DLC released in 2014) on my Xbox One S, and have been trying to pick up a few of the low-hanging achievements. One that looked particularly easy was "Replayer", which just required me to watch some replays in the "Replay Channel" section of the game under "Xbox Live BATTLE".

[image: Achievement: Replayer: Watch 30 replays via the Replay Channel! Isn't it fun watching people go at it tooth and nail!?]
[image]

Unfortunately, the Replay Channel doesn't seem to work. Every time I select one of the channels under the Replay Channel's "Channel Select" screen, I'm sent into a perpetual loading screen with the message "Sending data...".

[image]

After a minute or so, the loading screen will disappear and reappear, and if I've selected "Random" it will advance to the next channel, but no replay ever appears. I've left it running for more than half an hour as a test, and when I checked at the end it was still in this loop.

I initially assumed that this was a networking problem on my end, but I was able to play matches against other players through Xbox Live, and I came across [a few posts from other users encountering this problem in 2012](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/626633-super-street-fighter-iv-arcade-edition/60084362) [and 2013](https://steamcommunity.com/app/45760/discussions/0/846958724755843115/).

Is it still possible to get the "Replayer" achievement in *Super Street Fighter IV: Arcade Edition*? Is the Replay Channel broken, or is there some way to make it work, or an alternative that will satisfy the achievement?

Comment: On TrueAchivements I see that almost everybody who got this achievement (>99%) got it before 2013, but there are [a *few* users who got it in the last couple of years](https://www.trueachievements.com/achievementgamer.aspx?achievementid=60586&page=174), suggesting that it's not entirely impossible.

Comment: Could you record and watch your own replays?

Comment: @Moacir I can, and I've watched many of them. I'm not sure whether they count or not; I haven't been counting so I'm not sure if I've watched 30 yet. That would be tedious (compared with just leaving the Replay Channel running on its own), but I will try and see if that works, if there's no fix for the normal Replay Channel mode.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's any way to fix the generated channels ("Random", "Originals", "Newcomers", "Alpha", "Turbo & III", and "Boss"). However, you don't need them to complete the achievement.

You can still get the "Replayed" achievement by watching replays you've saved or downloaded, through menus such as "Battle Log". Sadly, this means you will need to manually start playing the replays 30 times; it won't automatically continue to play another one like the generated playlists would have.

[image: screenshot showing the "Battle Log" option in the "Channel Select" screen and the "Replayer Achievement Unlocked" message appearing over the post-replay menu]

Comment: I spent a while trying to find these these requests to load replays in Wireshark, to see if there was anything obviously wrong or that we could investigate, but that seems to be above my power level.